# Compare numeric types when types are unknown

Tags: c#

I have two values that I want to compare:

```
var value1 = someProperty.GetValue(x);
var value2 = someOtherProperty.GetValue(y);

if (value1 == value2)
{
   // do something
}
```

where `someProperty` and `someOtherProperty` are `PropertyInfo` objects. In other words, I'm getting the values by reflection.

The problem is if `value1` ends up being an `int` with the value `4`, and `value2` ends up being a `byte` with value `4`, I'd like to be able to tell those are the same. Is there a method to compare two numeric values without regard to their type? Preferably one that would still allow be to, say, compare two strings (so I can't really cast `value2` to `int` because it might turn out that it's a `string`).

Comment: `value1.ToString() == value2.ToString()`

Comment: @SamIam: That thought had occurred to me too, but it feels like a really inelegant solution. It could also cause problems if `value1` and `value2` are objects of some other type as they might both return `MyNameSpace.MyClass`.

Comment: In many places where I seen such stuff, it was done with a massive switch with reference checks being first, following by check if both types of the same type and implement IComparable, and then checks for value types, while ToString comparison being last.

Comment: I had assumed that you were intending to compare primitive types like ints, bytes, and strings.  If you're looking to compare more complex types than that, then you're in for some interesting challenges.  You'll probably have to have those types implement an interface which has a method which returns some sort of common comparable type

Comment: @SamIam: To be honest, right now I am looking only at primitives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One option is to use `dynamic`. This will make compiler to emit dynamic call site and asks the DLR to kick in to compare the objects at runtime.

```
object obj1 = (int)4;//Default is int, but added to make intent clear
object obj2 = (byte)4;
Console.WriteLine(obj1 == obj2);
Console.WriteLine((dynamic)obj1 == (dynamic)obj2);
```

Prints

```
False
True
```

Comment: I've (ab)used `dynamic` like this before to compare (`<` or `>`) numbers of the same type. It never occurred to me that it would work with different types, but it looks like it will work. Thanks.

Comment: will that compare int to string?

Comment: @SamIam Can you compare string to int if compile time type is known? If yes, then this can. (Answer is "no")